# Lens space to lens space surgeries

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Let $M_r(K)$ denote the slope $r$ surgery on a knot $K\subset M.$
Gordon conjectured and [Kronheimer-Mrowka-Ozsvath-Szabo](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0310164) proved that if
$S^3_r(U)=S^3_r(K)$ for some $r$ then $K=U$ (the trivial knot).

What happens when $S^3$ is replaced be a lens space $M=L(p,q)$?
In this context $U$ is defined as a knot such that $M-U$ is a solid torus. We require that $K$ is essential in $M$, meaning that it generates $H_1(M)$ so that $M-K$ has a well defined perhiperal structure and $M_r(K)$ is uniquely determined.

Does $M_r(K)=M_r(U)$ imply then that $K=U$? (Then $M_r(K)=M_r(U)$ is also a lens space.)

Final Remark: An "easy" case seems to be when $p=|H_1(M)|$ divides $|H_1(M_r(U))|$ since then we can bring it to $M=S^3$ case by taking a $p$-fold cover of both $M-U$ and $M-K$.

Comment: This paper classifies lens space surgeries on non-hyperbolic knots in lens spaces: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3264625 Presumably one could go through their list and determine which ones are equivalent to a lens space surgery on the unknot of the same slope. Also, there are two possible unknots in most lens spaces, corresponding to the cores of the two solid tori of the genus 1 Heegaard decomposition. These can occupy different homology classes in H_1(L(p,q)).

Comment: @IanAgol: Thanks -- that is very useful. Although I guess the hyperbolic case is harder.

Comment: One could look at the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504404 and see if one can use it to generalize their argument to lens spaces. The question is whether the Floer exact triangle allows one to determine the knot floer homology completely and characterize it as the unknot.